# Как повернуть по вертикале `dots` в slick slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как повернуть точки с горизонтального положения в вертикальное?

Comment: использовать флексы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно уменьшить ширину контейнера точек, тогда они станут вертикально располагаться. И спозиционировать его по правому (или левому) краю вертикально:

```
.slick-dots {
    width: 25px;
    bottom: auto;
    top: 50%;
    right: 25px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```